# Add active directory user to linux group upon sign-in

Tags: active-directory, ubuntu-12.04

I have Active Directory sign in working on an Ubuntu 12.04 box.  When an active directory user signs in, I would like to add them to the group sambasharers.  Where and how would I add this declaration?

I guess I should add that I am using Samba and winbind for authentication.

Comment: Even better: have whether or not you add the user to the local linux group depend on whether they are a member of a specific AD group.

Comment: That would definitely be a major plus.  Everyone who "should" be logging in to this box will be a part of the `progs` group in AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and probably not scalable solution:

Assuming you've already [set up your Linux box to authenticate to Active Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryHowto), then you just add each user who should be in the group to the `sambasharers` group on the UNIX Attributes tab in Active Directory Users and Groups. If you don't see the UNIX Attributes tab, see [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/921913).

Comment: Works for me.  I'm a linux person and am just getting used to the Windows side of things.  Thanks!